# Please suggest a Windows Object Picker C# wrapper

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, azman

I need to programmatically assign Windows and Active Directory users to the Window Authorization Manager (AzMan) roles via the Windows Object Picker. So I can invoke the "User and Group Permissions" window from my C# program.

Can anybody suggest a C# wrapper for the Windows Object Picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is custom dialog class [DirectoryObjectDialog](https://code.google.com/p/joco-library/source/browse/trunk/Source/FejesJoco.Framework.Windows/DirectoryObjectDialog.cs?r=65) that wraps the COM directory object picker.

Sample usage;

```
var dlg = new DirectoryObjectDialog
{
    MultiSelect = true
};
dlg.AddScope(DirectoryScope.Computer, users: true, groups: true);
dlg.AddScope(DirectoryScope.Domain, users: true, groups: true);
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (var sel in dlg.Selections)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", sel.Principal.SamAccountName, sel.Principal.Sid);
}
```

For detailed information available [here](http://joco.name/2011/03/27/directory-object-dialog-in-net-and-advanced-com-marshaling/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw your project, but a little confused whether it's possible to use it in commercial applications. On the main page it refers to the GPL license, while in the logs I see a note that it was converted to LGPL.

Comment: To clarify, project doesn't mine. There is another one http://adui.codeplex.com/ if you want. Its licence is Ms-PL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Which one is better and more stable by your opinion?

Comment: You're welcome, You should check which one meet your needs. I think adui.codeplex.com looks stable.

Answer (score 1):

I created a nuget very easy to use in C# https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker

Answer (score -1):

I like nuget package Tulpep.ActiveDirectoryObjectPicker

Here is a sample https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker

```
DirectoryObjectPickerDialog picker = new DirectoryObjectPickerDialog()
{
    AllowedObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Users | ObjectTypes.Groups | ObjectTypes.Computers,
    DefaultObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Computers,
    AllowedLocations = Locations.All,
    DefaultLocations = Locations.JoinedDomain,
    MultiSelect = true,
    ShowAdvancedView = true
};
using (picker)
{
    if (picker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (var sel in picker.SelectedObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sel.Name);
        }
    }
}
```